# Python - Ignoring self-signed certificate warnings when using McAfee Web API

Tags: python, ssl, mcafee

I am looking to make use of the mcafee-epo web api python library to automate some of my more repetitive maintenance tasks.

When trying to connect to our epolicy server, I receive an error stating that the certificate is invalid and the script crashes.

The error occurs because our ePO server uses self-signed certificates and therefore produces the usual security warnings upon connection.

Is there any built in function to the mcafee-epo package/module that can be used to disregard this security warning, or perhaps a method of exeception handling that will allow me to bypass the SSL errors produced?

Thanks!
A confused jr. admin

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code here https://bitbucket.org/davidism/mcafee-epo/src/ecc8836ea933f188dd9836e056cbaaabf768085d/mcafee_epo.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default, if you just make your call as such:

```
client = Client()
client('endpoint', verify=False)
```

I can't test it, but the mcafee library is using the requests module.  The way you ignore SSL in requests is to include the `verify=False` in your get/post calls.  The kwargs in `client` get passed to a wrapper around this requests module get.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Comment: No, if you look closely only the `files` and `params` arguments from `kwargs` passed to `__call__` are used. And recommending to turn off authentication is never really a good suggestion.

Comment: I didn't recommend anything, he asked how to disable warnings...and if you look closely, `params` gets updated with `kwargs` though I don't think it will use them in `_request`.  Probably will have to modify this module in order to use kwargs.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to make `requests` accept your self-signed certificate.

One way would be to set the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable to point to the certificate (bundle) requests should use:

```
os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = "/path/to/cert.pem"
```

The alternative would be to change the source of the library to pass the certificate bundle as `verify` parameter to `session.get()`/`session.post()`.

You should check out the requests documentation about [ssl cert verification](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)